# How can I count pulses using Pi GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I'm trying to build like a rev counter, so I want it to count how many times the circuit is closed every 0,5/1 second and then simply convert that to minutes to it'll be Revs per min. Which GPIO pins would I have to use? (I'm using Rasbian, latest version as of 3/12/15)
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 1st Gen Model B Rev 2

Comment: Have you tried googling raspberry pi rev counter or raspberry pi pulse counter?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample Python(2.7) script that may work:

```
import RPi.GPIO as g
from time import sleep
g.setmode(g.BCM)
g.setup(2, g.IN)
global revcount
revcount = 0
def increaserev(channel):
    global revcount
    revcount += 1
g.add_event_detect(2, g.RISING, callback=increaserev)
while True:
    sleep(60)
    print "RPM is {0}".format(revcount)
    revcount = 0
```

What this does is setup event detection on channel 2, which has a physical pull-up resistor. Anytime that pin detects a change from LOW to HIGH, it will increase the revcount, then print the current RPM each minute, resetting the counter each time.

Comment: So which GPIO pins do I have to connect the two wires to? (So then when the circuit is closed it adds to revcount) (sorry this is my first Pi project)

Comment: Connect the non-ground to BCM GPIO 2 (Board Pin 3), and the ground wire to any GND pin.

Comment: I get quite a few errors https://www.dropbox.com/s/4doikeonu1794fo/Photo%202015-12-04%2C%2012%2007%2038%20PM.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The comma in the `from time import sleep` line was my bad, shouldn't be there. However, the other error has to do with how you defined the function(you didn't). If you copy/paste my script directly into a text-editor (Leafpad, as you are running a GUI), then save it as "revcount.py", you can open it in IDLE or Python CLI (`python revcount.py`) to run it.

Comment: I get the error -> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BCIM' (I copied and pasted into leafpad and then opened in IDLE)

Comment: Another typo, no I in there. should be `g.BCM`. Fixed the code sample.

Comment: I now get the error- Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/Pi/Desktop/revcount.py", line 10, in <module> g.add_event_detect(2, g.RISING, callback = increase rev) RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

Comment: Also one quick question, one wire comes from GPIO 2 and the other from and ground pin and that should work?